# How to display smarty variable in tpl file

Tags: smarty, prestashop-1.7

I have an array with value. But when I want to display I see the HTML elements. This is the output:

```
Array ( [content] =>

Jesteśmy profesjonalistami ...
```

When I use `{$getContent['content']}` or `{$getContent.content}` I see

```
<p>Jesteśmy profesjonalistami
```

How to display this value without HTML elements?

Answer (score 1):

Try with `unescape:"htmlall"`

=> `{$getContent.content|unescape:"htmlall"}`

Answer (score 0):

```
{$getContent.content nofilter}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility would be `{$getContent[content]}`